# Vagrant : RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.5 required

Tags: python, vagrant

I am trying to run these codes: 
https://github.com/cndreisbach/call-for-service/blob/master/docs/src/development.md

I have been updating my python and made my default version of python 3.5

```
vagrant@cfs:/vagrant$ python --version
Python 3.5.7
```

When i run : `sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt`

```
    Cleaning up...
    Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/pandas
    Storing debug log for failure in /home/vagrant/.pip/pip.log
 RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.5 required.
```

How I can fix that issue?

Comment: What do you mean made my *default* version? Which python version is in your path (the one most at the top)>

Comment: `sudo pip3 install -r requirements.txt` You really shouldn't do that...

Comment: "How I can fix that issue?" by upgrading python to 3.5...

Comment: @Bluerine S I've changed it to python 3.5

Comment: @ruohola can you explain?

Comment: @U10_forward Im in python 3.5.7 => it should work no?

Comment: It's an issue with the numpy installer, see this questions:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57734032/installing-numpy-scipy-in-python-2-7-now-fails-with-runtimeerror-python-vers

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
python -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

there are some version conflicts sometimes