# Installing NumPy + SciPy in Python 2.7 now fails with "RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.5 required"

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy, pip

Installing numpy and scipy from source like this (say, in a fresh Python 2.7 `pyenv virtualenv`):

```
pip install numpy==1.14.6 scipy==1.0.1 --no-binary numpy,scipy
```

gets their installers to use a `~/.numpy-site.cfg` file that points to my openblas installation.

This used to work. Now it produces a long stack trace ending with:

```
      File "/usr/local/var/pyenv/versions/2.7.16/envs/issue/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
        exec(code, globals, locals)
      File "/var/folders/_b/q30qg_l50b5gvqd8y4_wb9h00000gn/T/easy_install-o9MJ5E/numpy-1.17.1/setup.py", line 31, in <module>
        if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.5 required.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Q. What changed?
Q. Why does it say `Python version >= 3.5 required.` in a Python 2.7 installation?
Q. How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `scipy 1.0.1` installer requires `numpy` as a prerequisite, but the multiple installers working together end up getting the *latest version of `numpy`* unless `numpy` is already present.

**What changed:** The latest version of `numpy` requires Python 3.5+, hence the error message.

So even though the `pip` command explicitly asked to `install numpy==1.14.6 scipy==1.0.1`, it triggers a newer `numpy` installer that fails on Python 2. (The last entry in the stack trace shows `numpy-1.17.1` requiring Python 3.)

The problem arises in the interaction between pip, the scipy and numpy installers, and easy_install. Details in [pip issue #6945](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6945#event-2597839850).

**Workaround:** Install `numpy` first. Then install `scipy`. Alternatively, the one-line install might work if you don't need the `--no-binary` option.

Comment: This post made me think that changing the order that numpy and scipy appeared in requirements.txt was sufficient. Only when I tried instally numpy without requirements.txt did I find the real problem with scipy, missing BLAS dev files in my Docker setup.

Comment: @cyrf Found this from another project, might also be what you're experiencing: "If you already installed `numpy` with `pip`, please note that `pip v7+`
  is caching packages installations, so changing the `blas` backend after
  any installation my not work as expected (eg. old backend still in use).
  Make sure to recompile `numpy` with the new settings by bypassing the cache with `--no-cache-dir`"

Comment: @Geordie I was building a docker image with `python:2-alpine` as the base. The python project listed numpy and scipy as dependencies in its setup.py. I do not believe numpy was already installed before attempting to install the project via pip. Only when I installed numpy, BEFORE the project, did I find an error message that scipy was complaining about blas missing.

Comment: @Geordie that's important to know! Do you have a reference link for that or any tips on just which situations cause that need to install numpy with `--no-cache-dir`?

Comment: @cyrf I **recommend against using Alpine linux** (after wasting a bunch of time on it) because its `musl libc` gets different math results than `glibc`! (Also the desired space savings from starting with a smaller Docker base image might not pan out when every image you build adds needed linux packages vs. a larger but shared base image.)

Comment: @Jerry101 I would like to buy you a beverage of your choice. Thank you! Your comment helped me avoid a nasty divide by zero exception.

Comment: @cyrf you're welcome! Here's a new post that warns about more Alpine pitfalls: [Using Alpine can make Python Docker builds 50× slower](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/alpine-docker-python/) ... also larger and run slower.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered an issue where scipy was been installed through a script and it was trying to install a version 1.7.1 which required python 3.7 at least and i hand 3.6. The workaround was i installed scipy myself and the version i got was 1.5.4.